Exchange or Graph Script for DDL multiple tenants Powershell
Hi all I have a specific problem trying to solve, have tried writing my own script but not getting results I want.
I work for a company that owns 4 other companies. They all operate as microsoft tenants for each other. My supervisor wants a DDL for each company . The first list should contain all users in the company who are not disabled(sign on blocked) and only the users. Some of the ‘resources’ are conference rooms which have an associated email. I have to exclude those.
Then a need to create serperate DDL’s which exclude the external tenant accounts, I think I can filter by domain I’d imagine.
So far im trying this
Set-DynamicDistributionGroup 'testdl1' -RecipientFilter {(-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'SharedMailbox')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'RoomMailbox')) -and (-not(RecipientType -eq 'MailContact')) -and -not(UserAccountControl -eq "AccountDisabled, NormalAccount") -and (-not(RecipientType -eq 'MailUniversalDistributionGroup')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'EquipmentMailbox'))}

This ends up giving me disabled users and DLs also. I don’t think it’s including conference rooms those.
I am using this
Get-Recipient -RecipientPreviewFilter ($FTE.RecipientFilter) | fl DisplayName

so I can look without the long GUID.
Any help is appreciated

You should be able to remove disabled accounts with (-not(UserAccountControl -band 2)) and specify only user objects with (UserAccountControl -band 512). I'd start there and see what else you need to add to get what is required. You should review the Recipient Filter page and Filterable properties for RecipientFilter page for more context.
